# DecimalUpDown decimal places

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro, xceed

I have wpf view with xceed DecimalUpDown control.

```
<xctk:DecimalUpDown Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="Notional" Increment=".1" Style="{StaticResource DecimalUpDown}" Minimum="0" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{x:Null}" />
```

Style for this control.

```
 <Style x:Key="DecimalUpDown" TargetType="xctk:DecimalUpDown" BasedOn="{StaticResource ErrorTemplate}">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="24" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,5,5,5" />
        <Setter Property="FormatString" Value="F" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
 </Style>
```

How can I change the number of decimal places on view? On viewmodel is what I write to control, but after lost focus it changes to two decimal places.

Comment: I got it. FormatString value F means default 2 decimal places. I rewrite to F4 and now I have 4 decimal places.

Comment: have you tried implementing a converter to display in the UI?